# Numerical average the eigenvalues of a stochastic matrix not match analytics

Tags: python

Assume a 2x2 matrix H. The diagonal is 0, while the off-diagonal terms are a complex-valued stochastic variable a(t). From analytical diagonalization, I know that the 2 eigenvalues are L1=sqrt(|a|^2) and L2=-sqrt(|a|^2), where |a|^2=a(t)a^*(t)

The problem is that the numerical evaluation of the eigenvalues and the analytics do not match.

Here is the full code of what I do:

1. Generate the stochastic variable a(t)
2. Generate the matrix H_m, which in turn is stochastic, i.e. it has many realizations
3. Calculate the eigenvalues of H_m for each trajectory.
4. Calculate the average of the eigenvalues for all trajectories.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm, eig
import time
from numba import jit, njit
import os


### We generate the stochastic variable. In this case, it is colored noise
@njit(fastmath=True)
def SDE_Param_Euler_Mauyrama(Nmax,Mmax,nth):
    alpha_list =np.zeros((Nmax+1,Mmax),dtype=np.complex64)
    for m in range(Mmax):
        alpha=0+1j*0
        for n in range(Nmax+1):
            alpha=alpha+(-kappa/2*alpha)*dt+np.sqrt(dt)*np.sqrt(kappa*nth)*w[n,m]
            alpha_list[n,m]=alpha
    return (alpha_list) 

#Parameters for the stochastic variable
kappa=1
nth=1

Mmax=2000 #number of samples

Tmax=3 ##max value for time
dt=0.01
Nmax=int(Tmax/dt) ##number of steps
t_list=np.arange(0,Tmax+dt/2,dt)   

## White noise paramters
phase=np.random.rand(Nmax+1,Mmax)
w = np.random.randn(Nmax+1,Mmax)*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*phase)

              
### Matrix to diagonalize
H1=np.array([[0,0],[-1j,0]],dtype=np.complex64)
H2=np.array([[0,1j],[0,0]],dtype=np.complex64)


## Generate the stochastic variable
alpha=SDE_Param_Euler_Mauyrama(Nmax,Mmax,nth)
alphap=np.conjugate(alpha)

## Calculate expectation values and plot them
mean_vu=np.array([np.mean(alphap[n,:]*alpha[n,:]) for n in range(len(t_list))])
mean_a=np.array([np.mean(alpha[n,:]) for n in range(len(t_list))])
plt.plot(t_list,mean_vu.real);
plt.plot(t_list,mean_a.real);
plt.ylabel(r'$<\alpha^{*}\alpha>$')
plt.xlabel(r'$\gamma t$')
plt.show();


eig1_m=np.zeros((len(t_list),Mmax),dtype=np.complex64) 
eig2_m=np.zeros((len(t_list),Mmax),dtype=np.complex64) 


## Calculate the eigenvalues of H
for m in range(Mmax):
    n=0
    for t in t_list[0:len(t_list)]:
        H=alpha[n,m]*H1+alphap[n,m]*H2
        eig1_m[n,m]=np.linalg.eig(H)[0][0]
        eig2_m[n,m]=np.linalg.eig(H)[0][1]
        n=n+1
        
eig1_t=np.mean(eig1_m,axis=1)
eig2_t=np.mean(eig2_m,axis=1)

plt.plot(t_list,eig1_t.real);
plt.plot(t_list,eig2_t.real);
```

Also, something interesting I found is that if I remove the imaginary part of the matrix H (just by removing the 1j), the eigenvalues should remain invariant except that now they are imaginary. However, numerically, I also get a disagreement.